# Is there a way to re-name a class created by D3?

Tags: d3.js

A svg path is create with `class="domain"`.  I'm assuming the following code takes care of that:

```
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format(".2s")).ticks(20).tickSize(width);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Now, when I wand to hide the path by using the following style:

```
.domain {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

obviously, it hides the path in all the other charts I have displayed.  Is there a way to re-name the path class or is there a way to hide only a specific path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not 100% sure I understood the question but) try this:

In CSS:

```
.domain.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

In JS:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ", 0)")
    .call(yAxis)
    .select('.domain')
    .classed('hidden', true);// should add class "hidden" to the domain
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to check this [selection.classed](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-classed)